# QProcess do not run an external application

Tags: c++, qt, process

I can run an external application using the following command:

```
system("/home/felippe/Área\\ de\\ Trabalho/Felippe/Mestrado/C_plus_plus/Codigos/build-Registration_ITK_CMAKE-Desktop_Qt_5_12_3_GCC_64bit-Default/Registration_ITK_CMAKE")
```

And the application runs successfully. But the system(.) command blocks the other commands until the application finishes. So I tried to implement this command in QT using the following code:

.h

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

#include <QObject>
#include <iostream>
#include <QProcess>

class foo : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit foo(QObject *parent = nullptr);

signals:


public slots:

   void process_started();

   void processError(QProcess::ProcessError error);

private:
   QProcess *process;

};

#endif // FOO_H
```

.cpp

```
#include "foo.h"

foo::foo(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    process = new QProcess();
    bool status = QObject::connect( process, SIGNAL( started() ), this, SLOT( process_started() ) );
    connect(process, &QProcess::errorOccurred, this, &foo::processError);
    QString file = "/home/felippe/Área de Trabalho/Felippe/Mestrado/C_plus_plus/Codigos/build-Registration_ITK_CMAKE-Desktop_Qt_5_12_3_GCC_64bit-Default/Registration_ITK_CMAKE";
    process->start(file);
    std::cout << file.toStdString() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "status: " << status << std::endl;
}

void foo::process_started()
{
    std::cout << "It worked" << std::endl;
}

void foo::processError(QProcess::ProcessError error)
{
    std::cout << "error enum val = " << error << std::endl;
}
```

main

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include "foo.h"  

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    foo *f = new foo();


    return a.exec();
}
```

When I run the process->start(file); I receive a error with value of 0, but when I run process->start(file, {"sudo"}); I receive a signal that the program run successfully, but anything is showed on the screen.

I'm trying to run on UBUNTU 16.04.

So, what is happening?

Comment: The documentation says "If the process starts successfully, QProcess will emit started(); otherwise, errorOccurred() will be emitted." Did you attach handlers to each of those signals to see what happens?

Comment: Did you mean to run `sudo .../Registration_ITK_CMAKE` instead of passing `sudo` as argument?

Comment: No, I pass sudo as an argument as stated in the command process->start(file, {"sudo"});

Comment: Best to check your the output/error streams of your process and/or run it under strace then.

Comment: You are invoking the `QProcess::start` overload that takes a single `QString` and will, therefore, probably pass the argument through a shell -- where whitespace/quoting could be significant.  You might want to try [`process->start(file, QStringList());`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#start) instead to avoid any shell 'involvement'.

Comment: G.M. I tried the following code (changing the folder of the executable):

QString folder = "home/felippe/";
    QString program = "Registration_ITK_CMAKE";
    process->start(program, QStringList() << folder);

But didn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious difference is that `system` passes your string to the shell, while `QProcess::start` takes a command and argument list separately.
I bet you will get "file not found" if you hook to the `errorOccurred` signal.

Solution: remove the `\\` from your string, as those are only needed if a shell is involved.

Comment: I tried this, changing the Qstring to QString file = "/home/felippe/Área de Trabalho/Felippe/Mestrado/C_plus_plus/Codigos/build-Registration_ITK_CMAKE-Desktop_Qt_5_12_3_GCC_64bit-Default/Registration_ITK_CMAKE";
 but it didn't worked.

Comment: When I do not pass any arguments I receive an 0 error, but when I pass sudo as an argument I do not receive any errors, but the program do not start.

Comment: Your question never mentioned anything about passing arguments... Please adapt your question.

Comment: I did some adaptations in the question.